# how to remove digit via regular expression

Tags: c#

now i hvae a string，i want to remove the beginning digit and '.' ,
i try Regex.Replace(str, @"^\d+[.]*",""), but not ok，below is my code.

thx

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = @"6.86.7.72022年10月缴纳的纳税证明";
    str = str.RemoveBeginDigit();
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
public static string Remove(this string str)
{   
     return Regex.Replace(str, @"^\d+[\.]*","");
}

the result is "86.7.72022年10月缴纳的纳税证明材料",but i wish the result is "年10月缴纳的纳税证明材料"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following regex:

```
^[\d\.]*
```

`^` asserts position at start of a line.

Match a single character present in the list below `[\d\.]`.

`*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).

`\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9]).

`\.` matches the character .

Comment: wow，NIU (praise of chinese style ) ！ Thanks a lot